# Exactly replicating a worksheet function in Excel VBA that has a Range input and output

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

For example, I tried replicating the UNIQUE function in Excel VBA (see below).

But when assigning "result" it gives me the error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

```
Function UniqueVals(list_of_vals As Range)

Dim result As Range
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(list_of_vals)
UniqueVals = result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of your function shouldn't be a Range, use `Variant`:

```
Function UniqueVals(list_of_vals As Range) As Variant

Dim result As Variant
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(list_of_vals)
UniqueVals = result

End Function
```

[image]